# Find out if an IP is within a range of IPs

Tags: ruby

How can you tell if an ip, say `62.156.244.13` is within the range of `62.0.0.0` and `62.255.255.255`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
>> require "ipaddr"
=> true
>> low = IPAddr.new("62.0.0.0").to_i
=> 1040187392
>> high = IPAddr.new("62.255.255.255").to_i
=> 1056964607
>> ip = IPAddr.new("62.156.244.13").to_i
=> 1050473485
>> (low..high)===ip
=> true
```

If you are given the network instead of the start and end addresses, it is even simpler

```
>> net = IPAddr.new("62.0.0.0/8")
=> #<IPAddr: IPv4:62.0.0.0/255.0.0.0>
>> net===IPAddr.new("62.156.244.13")
=> true
```

`IPAddr` will also work with IPv6 addresses

```
>> low = IPAddr.new('1::')
=> #<IPAddr: IPv6:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff>
>> high = IPAddr.new('2::')
=> #<IPAddr: IPv6:0002:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff>
>> (low..high)===IPAddr.new('1::1')
=> true
```

Comment: While jdl's post was fantastic, this is the best solution. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, I like this one. I had no idea that library existed.

Comment: [Here's the API link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) which provides some other useful functions for setting netmask and other goodies.

Comment: +1  There's also a `cidr.include? ip` [method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-include-3F) for those who find the `===` syntax a bit arcane.

Comment: Here is possible to use include? instead ===, include? is defined as alias to === in ipaddr class.

Answer (score 17):

There is a method `#include?`

And you can do just:

`IPAddr.new("127.0.0.1/8").include? "127.1.10.200"`

Comment: Not sure if it was possible 10 years ago when the other answers were first posted though...

Comment: It's definitely in 1.9.3 and newer. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-include-3F

Answer (score 12):

I would use [this killer little function](https://web.archive.org/web/20120130040849/https://techblog.floorplanner.com/2008/04/03/finding-the-correct-ip-address-in-rails/) to convert the IP addresses into integers, and then compare those.

```
def ip_addr_in_range?(low, high, addr)
  int_addr = numeric_ip(addr)
  int_addr <= numeric_ip(high) && int_addr >= numeric_ip(low)
end

def numeric_ip(ip_str)
  ip_str.split('.').inject(0) { |ip_num, part| ( ip_num << 8 ) + part.to_i }
end

def test_ip_addr_in_range(low, high, addr, expected)
  result = ip_addr_in_range?(low, high, addr)
  puts "#{addr} #{(expected ? 'should' : 'should not')} be within #{low} and #{high}: #{(expected == result ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL')}"
end


test_ip_addr_in_range("192.168.0.0", "192.168.0.255", "192.168.0.200", true)
test_ip_addr_in_range("192.168.0.0", "192.168.0.155", "192.168.0.200", false)
test_ip_addr_in_range("192.168.0.0", "192.168.255.255", "192.168.100.200", true)
test_ip_addr_in_range("192.168.0.0", "192.168.100.255", "192.168.150.200", false)
test_ip_addr_in_range("192.168.255.255", "192.255.255.255", "192.200.100.100", true)
test_ip_addr_in_range("192.168.255.255", "192.255.255.255", "192.100.100.100", false)
test_ip_addr_in_range("192.168.255.255", "255.255.255.255", "200.200.100.100", true)
test_ip_addr_in_range("192.168.255.255", "255.255.255.255", "180.100.100.100", false)

$ ruby ip_range.rb
192.168.0.200 should be within 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.0.255: PASS
192.168.0.200 should not be within 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.0.155: PASS
192.168.100.200 should be within 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.255.255: PASS
192.168.150.200 should not be within 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.100.255: PASS
192.200.100.100 should be within 192.168.255.255 and 192.255.255.255: PASS
192.100.100.100 should not be within 192.168.255.255 and 192.255.255.255: PASS
200.200.100.100 should be within 192.168.255.255 and 255.255.255.255: PASS
180.100.100.100 should not be within 192.168.255.255 and 255.255.255.255: PASS
```

Comment: Nice answer, complete with a full test suite, +1

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by jdl’s answer, but with a Range:

```
class String
  def to_ip
    split(".").inject(0) { |s, p| (s << 8) + p.to_i }
  end
end

("62.0.0.0".to_ip.."62.255.255.255".to_ip).include?("62.156.244.13".to_ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this approach for converting the IP address to an integer for range comparison:

```
# n_ip("192.1.1.23") will return the number 192001001023
def n_ip(input)
  input.split(".").collect{|p| p.rjust(3, "0")}.join.to_i
end

def ip_in_range?(from, to, given)
  (n_ip(from)..n_ip(to).include?(n_ip(given))
end
```

Now you can check the value as follows:

```
>> ip_in_range?("192.168.0.0",  "192.168.0.255","192.168.0.200")
ip_in_range?("192.168.0.0",  "192.168.0.255","192.168.0.200")
=> true
>> ip_in_range?("192.168.0.0",  "192.168.0.255", "192.168.1.200")
ip_in_range?("192.168.0.0",  "192.168.0.255", "192.168.1.200")
=> false
```

The integer returned is not a 32 bit representation of the IP address. The logic will work for all valid IP addresses.

Answer (score -1):

jdl's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518365/rails-find-out-if-an-ip-is-within-a-range-of-ips/3518518#3518518) is good. I would make the in_range? function a one-liner:

```
def ip_addr_in_range?(low, high, addr)
  (numeric_ip(low) .. numeric_ip(high)) === numeric_ip(addr)
end
```

Answer (score -7):

Don't make it any harder than it has to be.

```
def check_ip(ip)
  '62.0.0.0' < ip and ip < '62.255.255.255'
end

check_ip '62.156.244.13' #=> true
```

Edit: Or, if you're using Rails / ActiveSupport:

```
def check_ip(ip)
  ip.starts_with? '62'
end

check_ip '62.156.244.13' #=> true
```

Comment: Does this mean Ruby automatically recognizes IP addresses in strings?

Comment: Your method fails when checking for "10.0.0.2" to be between "10.0.0.1" and "10.0.0.10".

Comment: @deceze No. He's relying on alphabetical order, which only worked coincidentally for the numbers that he chose.

Comment: @jdl I'm actually sort of relieved to hear that. ;)

Comment: Actually, the first one will fail for both '62.255.255.255' and '62.255.255.26' too. Sorry about that. If you're looking to identify particular blocks though, I think that `ip.starts_with? '62.'` is really your best solution. Elegant and expressive :)