# Rails 3 - Whitelisting list of IPs via routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, constraints, ip

This is a two part question. I'm needing to restrict a rails site that I'm throwing on development server to only a few IP addresses, so the public can't access it. (Basic HTTP auth doesn't 'entirely' work as the auth breaks a Flash uploader in the project.)

Based on what I've Googled, this is what I've come up with in my routes file...

```
class WhitelistConstraint
  def initialize
    @ips = '127.0.0.1'
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @ips.include?(request.remote_ip)
  end
end

MyProject::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints WhitelistConstraint.new do
     # all my routing stuff here
  end
end
```

Works pretty good. However, I need to modify this in order to work with several IP addresses. I tried using a array on @ips, as well as looping through an each loop, but neither worked.

On top of that, the second part of my question...I may need to check only against a segment of the IP, like '127.0.0'. How would I do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I didn't know you could do this through routes, my approach would be to just have a `before_filter` in the `ApplicationController` and just have something that does:

```
before_filter :protect

def protect
  @ips = ['127.0.0.1', '203.123.10.1'] #And so on ...]
  if not @ips.include? request.remote_ip
     # Check for your subnet stuff here, for example
     # if not request.remote_ip.include?('127.0.0.1')
     render :text => "You are unauthorized"
     return
  end
end
```

Comment: I didn't know you could either. However, this solution worked right away for me and probably the better route to go. Could see it being an issue on going from development to production (which is temporarily the staging server), but it's only temporary and I can just add the IPs on both environments as needed. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `Rails.env.production?` and `Rails.env.development?` to check the environment in some sort of `if` construct to suit whatever you need to do. Good Luck :)

Comment: I suppose you could use this solution in conjunction with mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518365/rails-find-out-if-an-ip-is-within-a-range-of-ips

Comment: IP address in comment should be "127.0.0" instead of "127.0,0"

Answer (score 9):

what about using [NetAddr::CIDR](http://netaddr.rubyforge.org/classes/NetAddr/CIDR.html)?

and something like this?

```
class WhitelistConstraint
  def initialize
    @ips = []
    @ips << NetAddr::CIDR.create('127.0.0.0/8')
    @ips << NetAddr::CIDR.create('192.168.0.0/16')
  end

  def matches?(request)
    valid = @ips.select {|cidr| cidr.contains?(request.remote_ip) }
    !valid.empty?
   end
 end

 MyProject::Application.routes.draw do
    constraints WhitelistConstraint.new do
     # all my routing stuff here
     end
 end
```

This way you can specify the blocks of IPs that should be whitelisted, and not have to worry about the partial matches?

```
>> require 'netaddr'
=> true
>> @ips = []
=> []
>> @ips << NetAddr::CIDR.create('127.0.0.0/8')
=> [127.0.0.08]
>> @ips << NetAddr::CIDR.create('192.168.0.0/16')
=> [127.0.0.08, 192.168.0.016]
>> @ips.select { |c| c.contains? '192.168.10.1' }
=> [192.168.0.016]
>> @ips.select { |c| c.contains? '192.169.10.1' }
=> []
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, got a 'uninitialized constant WhitelistConstraint::NetAddr' error.

Comment: You will need to add the NetAddr Gem to you Gemfile if using rails 3 and do the bundle dance :) or Update your gem config if on rails 2.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Found an alternative solution above and is probably better as this is only a "temporary" thing for internal testing, but I'll keep the above in mind if I need something more complex.

Comment: Thanks Doon that gem is just what I was looking for to deal with my subnet masks in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply use apache's .htaccess:

1. Add the following to the http.conf or whatever conf file you have for apache and your rails app

> AllowOverride all

1. Create a file .htaccess in the rails folder and add the following

> ```
> Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
> Deny from all
> ```

Comment: Had tried this first with no success, and it was researching rails .htaccess that someone suggested using routes instead, which is what led me to the above. However, now that you mention it, I may not have had the AllowOverride all in my http.conf.

Comment: I haven't had time to give it a try as I went with another solution, but there is going to be a point in the project where I will need the .htaccess file, so this will come in handy then.

Comment: I finally did get .htaccess to work by editing Passenger's vhost file and adding AllowOverride all in there, and adding the .htaccess as above.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to surround your route declaration with a scope like so:

```
scope :constraints => lambda{|req|%w(127.0.0.1).include? req.remote_addr} do

  ... your beautiful routes

end
```