# Rails routes and authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, controller, routes

I am working on a simple Intranet application, although there are some users, there is no requirement for the general staff to login. They should be able to visit the Intranet from any computer and access what they need without logging in.

A number of our users are remote and they should be able to interact in the same way.

What I am trying to achieve is the following; a list of IPs & subnets that go straight to the root URL without logging in (admins can still login). Any visitor not on the list of whitelisted IPs & subnets should see the static access denied page. On that page should be a login link. Once logged in they can interact with the Intranet just as they can if they are in our whitelisted subnet. Once they log out they see the access denied page again.

I have the following code in my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :protect
  protect_from_forgery
  private  

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end

  helper_method :current_user

  def authorized?
    not current_user.nil?
  end

  def authorize
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not authorized" unless authorized?
  end

  def authorize_admin
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not authorized" unless authorized? && current_user.admin?
  end

  def protect
    @ips = ['127.0.0.1','123.123.123.12','192.168.5.0/24']
    allowed = false
      bremote_ip = 0
      request.remote_ip.split('.').each { |x| bremote_ip = (bremote_ip << 8) + x.to_i }
      @ips.each do |ipstring|
        ip, mask = ipstring.split '/'
        mask = mask ? mask.to_i : 32
        bip = 0
        ip.split('.').each { |x| bip = (bip << 8) + x.to_i }
        bmask = ((1 << mask) - 1) << (32 - mask)
        if bip & bmask == bremote_ip & bmask
          allowed = true
          break
        end
    end

    if not allowed
       render :template => "static/protect", :layout => "static"
       return
    end
  end

end
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: [Rails 3 - Whitelisting list of IPs via routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553874/rails-3-whitelisting-list-of-ips-via-routes)

Use the `netaddr` gem:

```
before_filter :protect

def protect
      @ips = []
      @ips << NetAddr::CIDR.create('127.0.0.0/8')
      @ips << NetAddr::CIDR.create('192.168.5.0/24')
      @ips << NetAddr::CIDR.create('123.123.123.12')
      valid = @ips.select {|cidr| cidr.contains?(request.remote_ip) }
      if valid.empty? and !authorized?
        authorize
        return
      end
end
```

**Edit**

In this case, the example above just skips the static protect page and redirects the user to the login page. I didn't understand the need for an intermediate static page?

Note: to avoid a "Too many redirects" error, you can add an `:except` to the `before_filter` statement. Or if you're using Devise, you add this to `config/application.rb`:

```
# In config/application.rb
module YourAppNameHere
  class Application < Rails::Application
  # Whatever else is already here...

    # The part to add
    config.to_prepare do
      Devise::SessionsController.skip_before_filter :protect
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, wouldn't that duplicate the same functionality that I have already? Block anyone not on the whitelist but not allow access at all to anyone who's not on the whitelist - even if they login?

Comment: @dannymcc Sorry - I didn't understand what was your main problem. Updated above.

Comment: You are, of course, correct. The static page is confusing things. I basically want anyone not on the whitelist to have to login to see anything and those on the whitelist should see anything that doesn't require authentication.