# postgres find IP address between 2 db columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ip-address, postgresql-9.3

I've a table of IP addresses. The table has two columns names `starting_ip` and `ending_ip`. The table looks like the following:
[image]

Now, let's say I have a random IP address. From that random Ip address, I want to know the `city_name`. That means I need to know that the random IP address falls between which range, based on `starting_ip` and `ending_ip`. Then find 1 record and get the `city_name`.

I wrote a query something like this:

```rb
class IpToCity < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :"ip_database_#{Rails.env}"
  
  scope :search_within_ip_range, -> (ip_address) do
    self.connection.select_all("
      with candidate as (
        select * from ip_cities
        where ending_ip >= '#{ip_address}'::inet
        order by ending_ip asc
        limit 1
      )
      select * from candidate
      where starting_ip <= '#{ip_address}'::inet;
    ")
  end
end
```

It's a scope, where I pass the random IP and get a single record. The problem is, the query works fine, but it's very slow. Any suggestion, how to make it faster?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518365/find-out-if-an-ip-is-within-a-range-of-ips

Comment: @MohamadKaakati Not really. It's finding an IP from between 2 range only. But I've multiple ranges stored in a postgres database. So, need a optimized query to find the range in which the random IP falls in.

Comment: I would only think of converting the starting ip and ending ip addresses to subnets and storing them within the database since it's the logical approach, and then I would pluck all the city_name and subnets from database and compare using `IPAddr.new("203.33.188.0/24").include? "203.33.188.111"`

Comment: @MohamadKaakati I don't think the approach you mentioned is suitable for a table containing 5276941 records. -_-

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: doesn't it work as

        select * from ip_cities
        where ending_ip >= '#{ip_address}'::inet AND starting_ip <= '#{ip_address}'::inet
        order by ending_ip asc
        limit 1
?

Answer (score 2):

Do all the rows match this format?

```
starting_ip  ending_ip
x.y.z.0      x.y.z.255
```

If so, then you can add another column for "prefix": x.y.z.

Then match the first 3 octets of the target against the prefix column.

When updating the DB, break rows that span more than one prefix into multiple rows.

The max number of rows is 16.8M (256<sup>3</sup>), which is small and only slightly bigger than your current 5M.

Comment: Not a bad idea. But in the db, they're not always in `x.y.z.n` this format. Can give it a try and see the outcome. Thanks

Comment: If you have to make updates to the DB, then there is probably no guarantee that the new rows will be in the desired format. In which case you would need to convert to the desired format anyway...